# otf to gdf for php

Tags: php, fonts, gd, truetype

Hi I am trying to use **imagestring** function.(I cannot use imagettftext function).
The problem is I want to use my own font which is not in gdf format.
So I need to convert my font(otf or ttf format) to .gdf font format.
Does anybody now how to achieve this? Or at least can I export each character to separate image file?

Comment: A quick google search reveals the answer: http://webcodingeasy.com/PHP/TTF-to-GD

Comment: Any update to this for unix platforms like OS X or BSD? as the online tool is now offline